# Unable to connect to RDS instance from outside VPC (ERROR 2003 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL Server)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I've created a VPC, and inside it an RDS instance.
The RDS instance is [publicly accessible](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding) and its settings are as follows:

[RDS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W8U6.jpg)

The security group attached to the RDS instance accepts all traffic:

[image: Security group settings]

All of my network ACLs accept all trafic.
However, I can't access my instance from a machine outside of my VPC. I get the following error:

```
    root@vps151014:~# mysql -h mysql1.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u skullberry -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql1.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

If I run the same command from an EC2 inside my VPC, I am able to connect.
I've tried connecting from several machines, all of them without a firewall (i.e. port 3306 open).

I'm obviously missing something but everything seems to be configured correctly. What could be the issue?

Comment: The `(110)` in the error message means "connection timed out," so definitely this is an IP connectivity issue.  Your RDS instance shows to be associated with two subnets.  In the VPC console, what is the default route of those two subnets? Is is an "igw-xxxxxxxx" or is it an "i-xxxxxxxx"?

Comment: Both subnets are implicitly associated with the [main route table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u4H6X.jpg) of the VPC.

Comment: Explicitly associating both subnets to a custom route table that routes all outbound traffic to the VPC's internet gateway makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.  The default route to the "igw" seemed like the most probable missing piece... and should in any event be necessary for this to work.  Assuming you gave the VPC enough time to reconfigure itself in the background after changing the subnet configs accordingly, I am out of ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was what you said. I was routing traffic with IP CIDR block 0.0.0.0/32 to the internet gateway, which obviously matches nothing. I changed it to <my-ip-address>/32 and now I am able to connect. Write your previous comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, the block you need for all IP addresses is `0.0.0.0/0`.  I'll post the answer.

Comment: How can we create subnet with CIDR 0.0.0.0/0  as it requires 16 or 24 netmask and range within the vpc IP address.
I'm able to access RDS from EC2 instance.
I want to access RDS from outside of the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For an RDS instance in VPC to "publicly" (Internet) accessible, all of the subnets it is attached to must be "public" -- as opposed to "private" -- subnets of the VPC.

A public subnet is essentially defined as a subnet that has the Internet Gateway object (igw-xxxxxxxx) as its route to "the Internet," or at least to any Internet destinations you need to access.  Typically, this is a destination address of `0.0.0.0/0`.  Public subnets must be used for instances (including RDS) that will have an associated public IP address, and should not be used for instances that will not have public IP addresses, since private addresses do not work across the Internet without translation.

A private subnet, by contrast, has its routing table configured to reach Internet destinations via another EC2 instance, typically a NAT instance.  This shows in the VPC route table associated with that subnet as i-xxxxxxxx, rather than "igw."  That machine (which, itself, will actually be on a different subnet than the ones for which it acts as a route destination) serves as a translator, allowing the private-IP-only instances to transparently make outbound Internet requests using the NAT machine's public IP for their Internet needs.  Instances with a public IP address cannot interact properly with the Internet if attached to a private subnet.

In the specific case, here, the subnets associated with the RDS instance were not really configured as something that could be simply classified as either a private or public subnet, because the subnet had no default route at all.   Adding a default route through the "igw" object, or, as OP did, adding a static route to the Internet IP address where connectivity was needed, into the VPC route table for the subnets fixes the connectivity issue.

However... If you experience a similar issue, you can't simply change the route table or build new route tables and associate the subnets with them, unless you have nothing else already working correctly on the subnets, because the change could reasonably be expected to break existing connectivity.  The correct course, in that case, would be to provision the instances on different subnets with the correct route table entries in place.

When setting up a VPC, it's ideal to clearly define the subnet roles and fully provision then with the necessary routes when the VPC is first commissioned.  It's also important to remember that the entire VPC "LAN" is a software-defined network.  Unlike in a physical network, where the router can become a bottleneck and it's often sensible to place machines with heavy traffic among them on the same subnet... traffic crossing subnets has no performance disadvantage on VPC.  Machines should be placed on subnets that are appropriate for the machine's IP addressing needs -- public address, public subnet; no public address, private subnet.

More discussion of the logistics of private/public subnets in VPC can be found in [Why Do We Need Private Subnet in VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212017/1695906) (at Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 2):

This already has a great answer, but AWS does create a public subnet for you when you choose the "publicly accessible" option. Rather, for me the problem was the default VPC security group. I was looking at the **Network ACL** rules - not **Security Group**. (Choosing the "publicly accessible" option in RDS adds the security group but does not automatically add the inbound rules.)

Click RDS and identify and click on the security group. Then under "inbound rules" add port 3306 and add your connecting IPV4 address, x.x.x.x/32 (or 0.0.0.0/32 - if you want the entire Internet to connect - but be careful with that).

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure the network you're connected to isn't blocking connections to another server on port 3306.  This was the case for me when connected to my corporate network.